# Is there a simple way to represent quotation marks in a xsl-stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, utf-8, quotation-marks

I want to output an XML File. In this XML File there is a tag with attribute-content inside quotation marks. How do i have to alter the XSL-Stylesheet to accomplish this?

I didn't find any other entry here that solves this problem.
How do I create the quotation marks before and after the xsl:value-of?

```
<xsl:for-each select="INPUTDOC/STRUCTURE">
    <xmlelement attribute="<xsl:value-of select="INPUT"/>"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

XML-Output should look like this (For every STRUCTURE-Element)

```
<xmlelement attribute="123456"/>
```

123456 being an example Input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you would use the value-of, or how to define an attribute on an element using xslt. Try the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="INPUTDOC/STRUCTURE">
    <xmlelement>
       <xsl:attribute name="[attributename]">
           <xsl:value-of select="INPUT"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
    </xmlelement>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Another and probably easier option is to use an attribute value template, as mentioned by Tim C in the comments.  That way your code would look like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="INPUTDOC/STRUCTURE">
    <xmlelement attribute="{INTPUT}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm new to XSLT so i didn't know about "xsl:attribute"

Comment: There is an even easier way. You can also simply do `<xmlelement attribute="{INPUT}" />`. The curly braces are known as "Attribute Value Templates" and indicate the expression inside should be evaluated rather than output literally.

Comment: Thanks @TimC I was not aware of those. I will add that to the answer.

Comment: Note that it can lead to issues if your element names start with XML